# Restful API becomes 404 when using the CXF at the same time

Tags: cxf, spring-integration

I have a project starts up with Spring Boot.
It has some restful API via Spring Integration inbound gateway.
Afterward, some webservice endpoint added to the project with CXF.

When I setup the CXFServlet mapping, all the restful API became 404.

Only I suspend the CXF config the restful API available again.

May I know if there is anything block the restful API or the spring integration inbound gateway during using CXF?

CXFServlet and Bus

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.kennie")
@ImportResource("classpath:cxf-services.xml")
public class SimbaAdapterApplicationConfiguration {

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/ws/*");
}

@Bean(name=Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
public SpringBus springBus() {      
    SpringBus bus = new SpringBus();
    bus.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    bus.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
    return bus;
}
```

XML configuration

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

<jaxws:server id="MyService" address="/ws/MyService" 
    serviceClass="com.kennie.IMyService" >
    <jaxws:serviceBean>
        <ref bean="myServiceImpl" />
    </jaxws:serviceBean>
</jaxws:server>
```

Service Interface

```
@WebService
public interface IMyService{

    @WebMethod
    public @WebResult(name = "Response") Response doRequest(
        @WebParam(name = "Request", mode = WebParam.Mode.IN)
        Request request
    );
}
```

Comment: please share the cxf configuration you are using. Also the URL you are trying to hit

Comment: I guess cxfservlet is intercepting your requests. Include also in question the web.xml section

Comment: @Sampada, CXF configuration added to the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CXF, but I know that Spring Integration HTTP is fully based on Spring MVC. So, if you can configure Spring MVC over CXF, all those Spring Integration HTTP Inbound Gateways will be available there as well.

I think your problem is somewhere with distinguishing Servlet mapping.

Looks like your REST API is routed through the CXF Servlet and that one doesn't like it, hence rejecting.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `CXF` to your code, all the RESTful APIs will be routed through it.

I see two contradictory settings with the way you have configured CXF -

1. The `url-mapping` . You are injecting CXF with this code:

   `@Bean
       public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
           return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/ws/*");
       }`

Meaning the url at which CXF is listening is `/ws/*`.

2. The `jax-ws` server! Firstly, you need to change it to `jax-rs` . `WS` is for `SOAP`. `RS` is for Restful. You have defined its address as:

   `<jaxws:server id="MyService" address="/ws/MyService"`

Meaning the server is listening at `/ws/MyService`

CXF and the jax-rs server are both listening at ws/ something. Now, this is not really a problem. You just need to add this to the URL you are hitting so that the complete URL is something like this:

```
http:<server>:<port>/<context-root>/<CXF Endpoint>/<jax-rs server address>/<REST API endpoint>
```

I am guessing you don't want ws appearing twice in the URL. Remove it from the `jax-rs` address.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I finally resolve my issue, and thanks.  I have to specify the MVC dispatcher servlet mapping for int-http.

Answer (score 0):

You can register more one servlet for http rest api, this method is tested and OK:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    //scanBasePackages = {"com.huawei.manage"}
    )
public class Application {


    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.scan("com.huawei.manage.hsf.controller");
        DispatcherServlet rest_dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext);
        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(rest_dispatcherServlet);
        registrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registrationBean.addUrlMappings("/*");
        return registrationBean;
```